# How to get rid of STDIN string while using the following function in PowerShell and two other things?

Tags: powershell, hashing

I am working on Windows 8.1 Pro with PowerShell 5.0.

Let's say I want to get a pure SHA-256 hash string of a file.

I defined a following function:

```
function sha256sum([string]$arg) {
    Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 $arg | Format-List | grep Hash
}
```

Example output:

```
PS C:\Users\Vlastimil\Downloads> sha256sum .\adr.exe
STDIN
Hash      : B3729AFDB438A1B264D75003379DC8ADD2DADDF91D01674F2844DB114D22D71B
```

It's almost working as to my wishes, might I ask:

1. How do I get rid of the first line saying `STDIN`?
2. How do I extract only the Hash string from the second line?
3. How do I convert the string to lower-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the STDIN out by using the following function:

```
function sha256sum([string]$arg) {
    Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 $arg | Format-List Hash
}
```

If you want to get rid of the extra empty rows it produces, use the following function:

```
function sha256sum([string]$arg) {
    (Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 $arg | Format-List Hash | Out-String).Trim()
}
```

To get the final result, you will want to use the following function though:

```
function sha256sum([string]$arg) {
    $Hash = Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 $arg | Select -ExpandProperty Hash
    $Hash.ToLower()
}
```